# Is "You are to choose a word to complete this sentence" correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions, vocabulary

I'm French and I have found in a text this direction for an exercise :
"You are to select a word to complete this sentence."
Is it correct?
I think it is "You have to select...". No?
Thank you

Comment: Try here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv103.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"You are to select a word"* is perfectly fine.

But what is this? What is this structure? `auxiliary be + to + infinitive`.

Here, it means:

> 1. **used to tell people they must or should do something**:
>
> [ + to infinitive ] *Their mother said they **were to** play nearby.*

---

- "**You are to**" is used in more formal and official situations.
- "**You have to**" is less formal and more subjective.

They both express obligation.

---

But be aware that *auxiliary be + to* could mean something else in a different context:

> 2. **used to say what will happen**:
>
> [ + to infinitive ] *The president **is to** decide this issue very soon.*

from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be)

Comment: The latter form also occurs in headlines, but without the auxiliary *be* (which is seen as superfluous).

Answer (score -1):

Either way is correct, but *you are to* is friendlier than *you have to*; the second version makes it clear that someone is commanding you to do something, while the first version presents what the speaker is saying as instructions but not necessarily a command.

Comment: In Britain, an instruction can be a command. I instructed my clerk to prepare a report. I said "You are to prepare the report by 12 noon".

Comment: I don't agree that *you are to [infinitive]* is "friendlier" than *You must  / You have to [infinitive]*. If anything I'd say that it's often much *less* friendly, since it's inherently more dismissive of how you as an individual might feel about how you've been pigeonholed and your fate arbitrarily decided (by the speaker himself, or some higher authority).